# How to save all files in tabs on Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, tabs

If I have multiple files in tabs on VIM and I edit few of them. How to save them with one command?

Comment: To save all and exit, try: `:xa`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The command `wa` (short for `wall`) will write all changed buffers. You can also use `:tabdo w`, which is definitely exactly what you want, and generalizes nicely.

Comment: `:tabdo w` is not equivalent to `:wa`. If a tab has multiple windows open, `:tabdo w` will only save the currently focused window in each tab, whereas `:wa` will save all of them. `:wa` will also save hidden buffers.

Answer (score 29):

Just do

`:wa`

(followed by return) which is a shorthand for

`:wall`

Also to "save everything and exit" you can do

`:wqa` or `:xa`

(="write-quit-all")

Answer (score 12):

It's possible to suffix `a[ll]` for a number of Vim command-line commands (i.e. type `:` when in normal mode), include:

- `:wa` - save all tabs / unsaved buffers
- `:xa`/`:wqa` - save all tabs / unsaved buffers and exit Vim
- `:qa` - exit vim (will warn if unsaved buffers exist)

Answer (score 7):

To save all the files just use an a after the write command to write all the files.

```
:wa
```

Answer (score 4):

And you can use `:tabdo! w` too, I'm just adding this, because it's useful for other things too (e.g. `:tabdo! g/somepattern/ s/something/anything/`... I use it all the time for refactoring purposes...)

Comment: I'd recommend a read on `help :g`, but in short, it only applies the next command (in my case the `s/something/anything/` to the lines, that matches `somepattern`). Yeah I know, that usually I can do that without the `:g`, but sometimes not (I used to match multiline regexes via `\\_.`), and the best part is `:g`'s little "sister" `:v`.

Comment: See [my comment on the other post above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246268/how-to-save-all-files-in-tabs-on-vim#comment20689678_4246310) for why `:tabdo w` may not work as expected.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks TIL about those behavior of `:tabdo w`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `:wall` command