# How to save the files opened in all windows and tabs in Vim?

Tags: vim

I’d like to save the files opened in all vertical/horizontal windows? Is it possible without going to each window and executing the `:w!` command?

Comment: To save all and exit, try: `:xa`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save all files in tabs on Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246268/how-to-save-all-files-in-tabs-on-vim)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To save only those buffers that opened in the current tab page and not
those that are hidden, run the `:write` command for every open window:

```
:windo w!
```

In order to save all open buffers regardless of the corresponding
windows’ locations, run the `:wall` command:

```
:wa!
```

There is also a similar command

```
:bufdo w!
```

but it does not behave in quite the same fashion. Both commands affect
hidden buffers, but `:wall` does not attempt to write the buffers
that do not have a file name set.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do this with `:wa`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:wall`

It writes all changed buffers (but it will also save the hidden one).